# How to setup two columns vith vertical separator in framed figure

Tags: multicol, framed

How to put in two **columns** mode **verbatim** (block) text with **vertical** line in **framed** box, in **figure**.

The problem is that when the two columns are put in frame the vertical line disappears

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{framed}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{verbatim}
first column
\end{verbatim}
\columnbreak
\begin{verbatim}
second column
\end{verbatim}
\caption{6-7}
\label{fig:06_07}
\end{multicols}
\end{framed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you accept a `sidebyside` `tcolorbox` instead of `multicol` and `framed`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside]
\begin{verbatim}
first column
\end{verbatim}
\tcblower
\begin{verbatim}
second column
\end{verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}
\caption{6-7}
\label{fig:06_07}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just the `default` solution. It's possible to produce `solid` vertical line, sharp corner, different colors for left and right columns, different width, ...

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi, the desired settings are ```\begin{tcolorbox} [sidebyside, colback=white, sharp corners, enhanced, segmentation style=solid]
 ```

Comment: Yes. Good work!